# Data format and X/Y configuration for dynamic csv display

Tags: csv, highcharts

I am trying to understand the demo at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax which plots data using a csv file fetched through an ajax call.

Highcharts appears to assume that first column is X axis, with subsequent columns being Y axes data with the same units. The `series` part in the provided jsfiddle can be completely removed and example still runs the same, so I believe its not being used when data `csv` property is set. I was also unable to find any explanation of the csv property in Highcharts [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

***Note***: This example is using a different approach from [other csv documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json) on the site.

The csv format allowed does not seem to support [double quotes](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). Also, I can get data with 2 columns to render, but I was wondering if there is any way to tell Highcharts to use 2 particular columns for X & Y axes while ignoring other columns in the input csv.

- Is there a good reference to configuration settings available when using data csv property as in the given example?
- Is there any example of a composite chart with spline & scatter plots created dynamically from csv data fetched thru ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs for data.js plugin is described inside the [data.js](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js) file.

And demo for spline and scatter: http://jsfiddle.net/3qv11owm/

```
        series: [{
            type: 'scatter'
        }, {
            type: 'spline'
        }]
```

Options from `series` array are merged with series from CSV.